# Call EJB3 Local bean through Remote bean from external JVM

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, weblogic-10.x

Not terribly experienced using EJB, and I ran into the following problem with which I hope one of you guys can help out.

Suppose the following situation: a set of `@Local` beans have been defined to provide access to a database. These beans are very simple, and are deployed on **application server A** (Weblogic 10.3.3). We want to provide access to these *local* beans via *remote*, and since we already have a "services" module set-up for providing external access to our services, our idea was to create a new `@Remote` service that uses the *local* beans described above (injected via `@EJB`). These service beans are also deployed on application server A. For example:

```
@Local
public interface DatabaseBeanLocal { doStuff(); }

@Stateless(name = "ejb/DatabaseBean", mappedName = "DatabaseBean")
public class DatabaseBean implements DatabaseBeanLocal { doStuff() { ... } ; }

@Remote
public interface ServiceBean { doSomeOtherStuff(); }

@Stateless
public class ServiceBeanImpl implements ServiceBean
{
    @EJB(name = "ejb/DatabaseBean", mappedName = "DatabaseBean")
    private DatabaseBeanLocal myDatabaseBean;

    ... methods etc. ...

}
```

The client that will actually use these *remote* beans is actually run on a different application server; **application server B** (also Weblogic 10.3.3). When we look-up the `ServiceBean` bean from our client, that works fine. When we call a method on it that needs access to `DatabaseBean` however, the call fails. The Weblogic server says it cannot find a bean for the `DatabaseBean` interface.

My questions: is this set-up even possible? In other words: will Weblogic (or another container) inject the local bean into the remote bean so that the client gets an instance of the remote bean that is capable of calling actions on the local bean (I assume not, but I'm asking anyway to be sure)?

If not, the I guess we'll have no other choice than to skip the service layer and provide direct access to the `DatabaseBean` example above via `@Remote`.

#### Update 1

After doing some tests, simply defining `DatabaseBean` above as `@Remote` rather than `@Local` "fixes" this issue. Ofcourse, this is not really a fix since this will call the `DatabaseBean` remotely, which is ridiculous because it's in the same module as the service. I'm starting to suspect that wrapping a local EJB with a remote EJB is simply not possible.

#### Update 2

What we've found so far:

- We've not been able to manually inject the local EJB so far, because we cannot actually find it at runtime.
- Weblogic apparently does not include local EJBs in the JNDI tree.
- Calling the `ServiceBean` from outside the AS on which it is deployed still does not work, because the dependency on the local EJB is never resolved, or resolved client-side which means it's not found.

Comment: Did you configure the EJB (implementation) of the DatabaseBean?

Comment: I updated the code to include more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get this issue resolved. the following configuration works for Weblogic 10.3.3 and allows for a *remote* EJB to use a *local* EJB, where the remote EJB can be called from anywhere.

Ultimately — after **a lot** of testing — the trick was apparently specifying a `beanName` value for the `@EJB` annotation used to mark the local bean as a dependency of the remote bean. Doh!

#### Deployment

- `@Local` EJB is deployed on AS-A in EAR-1 (in its own module/JAR)
- `@Remote` EJB is deployed on AS-A in EAR-1 (in its own module/JAR)
- Client code that calls the remote service is deployed on AS-B in its own EAR archive

#### Annotations

The **local** EJB is a very simple and straightforward EJB bean, with the following interface and implementation:

```
@Local
public interface LocalBeanLocal {
    // Implementation omitted
}

@Stateless(name = "LocalBean")
public class LocalBean implements LocalBeanLocal {
    // Implementation omitted
}
```

The **remote** EJB is again a relatively simple EJB bean, except that it has a dependency on `LocalBean`. This dependency is expressed through the `@EJB` annotation; but it would seem that the `beanName` attribute is required for Weblogic to resolve this dependency correctly. *Without* the `beanName` attribute, calling the remote EJB would not work for us (in the sense that there would always be some kind of error when the local bean was involved)!

```
@Remote
public interface RemoteBeanRemote {
    // Implementation omitted
}

@Stateless(name = "RemoteBean")
public class RemoteBean implements RemoteBeanRemote {

    @EJB(beanName = "LocalBean")
    private LocalBeanLocal localBean;

    // Implementation omitted
}
```

What is apparently important here is that the `beanName` attribute in the remote service dependency declaration (`@EJB(beanName = "LocalBean")`) should have *the same value* as the bean name defined in the local bean implementation (`@Stateless(name = "LocalBean")`).

#### Lookup

Getting a reference to your remote EJB is done the traditional way, there doesn't seem to be a specific requirement. In our case, we look-up the remote service via JNDI.

Comment: "the beanName attribute in the remote service dependency declaration (...) should have the same value as the bean name defined in the local bean implementation (...)" - well, that's sound reasonable for me - in implementation you define bean name and then you inject the bean named so, so these values must be equal. However, I'm interested why you had to specify it in the first place. Did you test it on different Application Server?

Comment: No we didn't - we only have access to a Weblogic at the moment. It's entirely possible that with JBoss AS, we wouldn't need to specify the attribute, but I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

Local means local to EAR not to AS.

Your local and remote Beans must be in same EAR (not only in same AS). Are they?

-- edit --

Hmm.. If they're in the same EAR then it should work. I.e. answer to your question *"is such a setup even possible?"* is Yes.

Unfortunately now we're talking abt pure and simple debugging. First thing I would do is try and check if teh local bean (`DatabaseBean` I guess) is actually registered and working using [WebPhere UTC](http://wpcertification.blogspot.com/2011/04/universal-test-client-application.html) equivalent in WebLogic (I never worked in WebLogic). I can list a 100 other things you can check for more logs/traces/symptoms but well, that's the way debugging goes.

Comment: Yes, they are. All of our modules (for application server A) are packaged into the same EAR and then deployed.

Comment: I get the impression that when I call the remote service on application server B, it's application server B that will try to resolve the `@EJB` injection of the local bean. That obviously doesn't work because the local bean is not deployed on B, it's deployed on A. Are you sure that this *should* work?

Comment: @pHk I'm not sure what you mean by "injection", I have done this myself; differences were that AS-B was a stand alone client and it was EJB-2 not 3. Also just theoretically, when you use a local EntityBean inside a remote SLSB's impl (a common case) you can still call SLSB from outside AS.

Comment: We've been experimenting with this all day now, and we just cannot get this to work on Weblogic 10.3.3. It seems like the Weblogic EJB container refuses/can not properly inject a local bean in a remote service. What's more is that local EJBs *aren't even included* in the JNDI tree by Weblogic. This might be a Weblogic issue more than it is an EJB issue.